# More effective method then Switch in Android development (Java)

Tags: java, android, performance, switch-statement

I am developing a game in Android Studio (Java). In my project there is a method which is used to generate instances of an object and populate them in an ArrayList. Basically what it does, it just makes "enemy space ships" to shoot at the player "randomly". In other words, after every frame the method generates a random number and if the number is 1, then the ArrayList is populated by a "laser blast" object instance which makes the enemy space ship to shoot.

**My question would be: Is there a better and less costly way to simulate this kind of event? Or maybe there is a way to make this existing method more efective and less costly?**

Here is the method:

```
public static void generateRandomNumber(ArrayList<EnemyShipLaserBlast> listOfLaserBlasts, int x, int y) 
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int number = random.nextInt(50);
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            listOfLaserBlasts.add(new EnemyShipLaserBlast(x, y));
            break;
        default:
            //do nothing
    }
 }
```

Comment: You only have one case? What's wrong with an if statement?

Comment: Yes, I am just checking if the number is 1, all the other cases would mean that nothing should happen. So using if statement would be more efective?

Comment: It's cleaner, yes. The bytecode may be different, but  there's little to no difference in that and what you have

Comment: You could create your `new Random()` as a final instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, since you have just one case, you should probably use an "if" statement instead of a "switch" - there will probably not be a performance gain, but the code would be easier to read.

I think that the change that would make the most impact on performance would be to make the Random a static (I would make it a static final). That way, you would construct the Random once for the whole application, instead of every time the method gets called. This saves time both in object construction and garbage collection.